WCF service Message security using WsHttpBinding
I'm trying to use Message security for my service, but I keep failing.I'm new to wcf developing, so I've relied on copying others but this is trickier.
First I created my service and my client. After confirming that they work as intended I started to look for ways to encrypt my communication and I figured that what I need is WsHttpBinding, so I started searching for a way to include it in my service. I found some videos showing how to do it, but something keeps going wrong. I'm including the Web.config file in its before and after state.
before (it works but no encryption):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

after (doesn't work):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="PDService.PDService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PDService.IPDService" bindingConfiguration="CustomHttp"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CustomHttp">
          <security mode="Message">
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

and this is the client (auto generated by vs):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPDService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:53181/PDService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPDService"
                contract="PDServiceReference.IPDService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IPDService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>



try to find an existing example that uses a configuration like you want it, or as close as possible to it.   2) use the Microsoft Service Configuration Editor (VS Tools menu) to make changes to the config - it makes it easier to see what might be missing.   3) to troubleshoot runtime issues, have WCF traces generated on either or both sides (configurable via the tool just mentioned) and review them with the associated viewer. Google WCF tracing for more info on this last point.


If your client is a asp.net core project, it does not support wshttpbinding. Here is the relevant post:

my client is a vb.net console app
